# XmlSerialize a class and send it from client to server

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, client-server

I have 2 clases:

```
 public class products
{
    public string category;
    public string name;
    public double price;
    public string desc;
    public string version;
    public string logoURL;
    public string imgURL;
    public string prod;

    public string Category
    {
        set { categorie = value; }
        get { return category; }
    }
```

and:

```
    [Serializable()]
public  class groupProducts
{
    public products[] produse;
}
```

I want to XmlSerialize the groupProducts class and send the data from a server via TCP conection to a client!
I've tried something like:

```
   groupProducts gp = new groupProducts();
XmlSerializer xmlSel = new XmlSerializer(typeof(groupProducts));
TextWriter txtStream = new StreamWriter("xmlStreamFile.xml");    
xmlSel.Serialize(txtStream, gp); 
txtStream.Close();
try
{
Stream inputStream = File.OpenRead("xmlStreamFile.xml");
// declaring the size of the byte array to the length of the xmlfile
msg = new byte[inputStream.Length];
//storing the xml file in the byte array
inputStream.Read(msg, 0, (int)inputStream.Length);
//reading the byte array 
communicator[i].Send(msg);
}
```

but it when I Deserialize it on the client side - the XML file has some weird data in it!

Do you have any idea what could it be? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Define "weird data". Is it still valid XML?

Comment: Yes - it was still XML data but only some of it! I've managed to correct it but now the data is written twice!

Comment: I have no idea what that means... can you post some example output?

Comment: Eg. <categorie>Android,</categorie>
    <numeProdus>Angry Birds,</numeProdus>
    <categorie>Android,</categorie>
    <numeProdus>Angry Birds,</numeProdus>

Comment: You can edit your answer to post full XML on the other side. I suspect buffering or parallel processing is the issue here. Perhaps getting rid of the temp file as LB suggested will fix it, but maybe not... Also unclear what is the type of `communicator[i]` and what does Send() method do - those could be source of the issue to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- To be safe I would use an encoding while opening `StreamWriter`

2- In `inputStream.Read(msg, 0, (int)inputStream.Length);` Read does't guarantee that you will get `inputStream.Length` bytes from stream. You have to check the returned value.

3- You don't need a temp file. Use `MemoryStream`

```
XmlSerializer xmlSel = new XmlSerializer(typeof(groupProducts));
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
xmlSel.Serialize(m);
communicator[i].Send(m.ToArray());
```

Comment: please use `using` on `MemoryStream`

Comment: @IliaG , It is just a tradition. MemoryStream doesn't have any resources to dispose.